# How can I handle a custom POST origin with Nancy?

Tags: c#, http-headers, nancy

I have a third party server that POSTs data to my C# Nancy console application with the following request;

```
POST //172.16.100.20 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: P2000/3.6.0
Host: 172.16.100.20:40000
Server: remotesitename
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 2744

<MessageBase>
<BaseVersion>301</BaseVersion>
<MessageType>3</MessageType>
....
```

However I just can't seem to get Nancy to receive the request. I've tried various catchall routes such as

```
"(.*)"
"{uri*}"
"//172.16.100.20"
```

But none of them work with the above request (they generally work from a browser or Fiddler).

I've also tried hooking in to the module and application Before handlers, but they don't fire too.

The same code works if I use a correct request from my own test applications with ORIGIN as follows;

```
http://172.16.100.2
```

This simulated request was issued from the same third party server to the listening Nancy server over the local network and without firewalls or virus scanners.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Sounds like the requests are not reaching Nancy at all. So there is like something handling/rejecting before Nancy gets a chance. Could be firewall, web server, proxy, load balancer - you name it.

Comment: Sorry I should have added that the code does work if I simulate a correct request such as POST http://172.16.100.2

Comment: Is the simulation running on the same machine as the 3rd party server?

Comment: The simulation is from the same third party server as the Bad request. So over the local network and through the same stack on either side (no firewall or virus services enabled)

Comment: I've moved on to using my own code to listen on a socket and parse the POST header but it would be good to understand how Nancy handles this as its a great library and I will use it more in future I'm sure.